# Two variables in one foreach statement laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The first @foreach below brings the user who created the post. I need the output to be the user who shared the post, which is returned by the second @foreach below.

First Foreach :

```
@foreach ($friendShares as $friendShare)
<p> {{$friendShare->body}} by {{$friendShare->user->getname()}}</p> 
@endforeach
```

Second Foreach :

```
@foreach ($shares as $shares)
<p> {{$shares->user->getname()}}</p> 
@endforeach
```

My question is, What is the correct syntax to integrate the {{$shares->user->getname()}}  into the @foreach ($friendShares as $friendShare) , which could be something like this :

```
@foreach ($friendShares as $friendShare , $shares as $shares )
<p> {{$friendShare->body}} by {{$shares->user->getname()}}}}</p>
```

Comment: Either use join in  query while getting data from db or  make a array having post id as key and share name as value. lke $sharesArray[postid] = "name of user";

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to go over two arrays in a single foreach, you could however do the following:

```
@for ($i = 0;$i < min([count($friendShares),count($shares)]);$i++)
   <p> {{array_values($friendShares)[$i]->body}} by {{array_values($shares)[$i]->user->getname()}}}}</p>
```

This should achieve your desired result.

Comment: I received this error  :  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: Sorry, I assumed those two variables were arrays , updated to cast them.

Comment: Still having the following error  ... and many thanks for your support and patience :) .    Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\wamp\www\StuffSync\resources\views\profile\index.blade.php) .... which is in the line of the for loop

Comment: Ok, this isn't going to work then. I'll revert it back in case it can help someone else who is trying to do this with arrays.

Comment: Any recommendation for my case ?

Comment: @AbdallahSakre update your question with a sample of what `$friendShares` and `$shares` looks like (i.e. partial output from a `print_r`) so it's more clear what the structure is like.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use two nested foreach.... for that store all the values in some variable

```
@foreach ($shares as $shares)
<p> <?php $shares_get_name = $shares->user->getname() ?></p> 
   @foreach($friendShares as $friendShare)
<p> {{$friendShare->body}} by {{$shares_get_name}}</p> 
@endforeach
```

I hope this is what you wanted...if not can you please elaborate ur integration needed

Answer (score 0):

I changed the relationships in the controller to a query, which was more easy and clear to me (but still used relationships to get the list of $myFriends):

**Controller code**

```
        $myFriends = Auth::user()->friends()->lists('id');
        $sharedPosts = DB::table('shares')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
            ->join('posts',  function($join){
                    $join->on('posts.id', '=', 'shares.post_id');                   
                })
            ->where('shares.user_id', '=', $myFriends) 
            ->get();

return view('profile.index')
        ->with('friendShares', $sharedPosts);
```

**View code :**

```
@foreach ($friendShares as $friendShare)
<p> {{$friendShare->body}} by {{$friendShare->first_name}} {{$friendShare->last_name}}</p> 
@endforeach
```